# Having issues mounting raw disk image in OSX

Tags: macos, filesystems, mount, disk-image

I have received this disk image from a embedded linux device. I need to mount the image and check some files on it.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
> hdiutil attach -nomount ~/Downloads/dskimg.img
/dev/disk3              FDisk_partition_scheme
/dev/disk3s1            Windows_FAT_32
/dev/disk3s2            Linux
```

Then trying to mount it to a folder:

```
> diskutil mount -mountPoint ~/mount /dev/disk3s2
Volume on disk3s2 failed to mount
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

I wrote the image to SD card, but after that I don't see any file systems or anything after mounting it.
I have set up macFUSE to be able to see linux file systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out I had to use ext4fuse **specifically** to mount.

```
ext4fuse /dev/disk3s2 ~/tmp/MY_DISK_PARTITION -o allow_other
```